# Maximum limit for enterprise IPA file (in-house)?

Tags: ios

I'm building an enterprise IPA file.

What's the maximum app size limit of the IPA file that I can build?

According to this apple link:

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev611e0a21f

1) Maximum executable file size (iOS 9.0 and later): 500 MB

--> What is the meaning of "Maximum executable file size?  is it .h .m .a .framework files? how do I check it?

2) Your app’s total uncompressed size must be less than 4GB. 
--> is this the size of the xarchive file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1.) Maximum executable size

The documentation states:

> each Mach-O executable file — for example, `app_name.app/app_name` — must not exceed these maximum file sizes:
>
> for iOS 9.0 and later: 500 MB  (For the total of all __TEXT sections in the binary.)

So you

- uncompress your `ipa` file (which in fact is simply a zip file, just rename it :-)
- go to `Payload\app_name.app`
- find out the size of  app_name

For example:

```
user$ unzip Enterprise.ipa 
user$ cd Payload/Enterprise.app/
user$ size Enterprise
__TEXT  __DATA  __OBJC  others  dec     hex
8192    4096    0       20480   32768   8000    Enterprise (for architecture armv7)
8192    4096    0       20480   32768   8000    Enterprise (for architecture armv7s)
```

So you simply sum up the size of the `__TEXT` sections and check if it fits.

### 2.) Total uncompressed size

This is simple the size of *everything* that gets uncompressed - see above: .ipa is simply a zip format, therefore just uncompress it and check the size of all:

```
user$ du -k Payload/
4       Payload//Enterprise.app/_CodeSignature
8       Payload//Enterprise.app/en.lproj
128     Payload//Enterprise.app
128     Payload/
```

(so here it's 128 kB, quite room for improvements I guess)